# Infinite scroll with ListView and nativescript-vue

Tags: listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would like to know if it's possible to implement infinite scroll on ListView with nativescript-vue.

Currently, I see only the **@itemTap** event, but I don't see the others events to use with ListView and nativescript-vue to implement the infinite scroll.

```
<ListView class="list-view" v-for="(post, indexPost) in posts" @itemTap="loadMore">
  <v-template>
    <StackLayout class="list-element" orientation="vertical">
      <post :post="post" />
    </StackLayout>
  </v-template>
</ListView>
```

I would like to listen the scroll on the ListView.

With vue-native, I implement it with this on scroll-view :

```
<scroll-view :on-scroll="(event) => {loadMore(event)}" :scroll-event-throttle="400">
  <post v-for="(post, indexPost) in posts" :post="post" />
</scroll-view>

...

loadMore: function (event) {
  let paddingToBottom = 0;

  paddingToBottom += event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;

  if (event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >= event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height - paddingToBottom) {
    this.getData()
  }
},
```

I would like to implement the same with nativescript-vue...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nativescript's RadListView instead of the regular ListView.
Here is a link to the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-ui/rad-list-view.html) and [api](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radlistview).

`RadListView` has a property called `loadOnDemand` which let's you add a way to trigger the `getData` and update the list view.

Some additional information about the `loadOnDemand` functionality [here](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/radlistview/load-on-demand)

The code should be similar to this:

```html
<lv:RadListView id="ls" items="{{ dataItems }}"  row="0" loadOnDemandMode="Manual" loadMoreDataRequested="{{onLoadMoreItemsRequested}}">
```

```js
public addMoreItemsFromSource(chunkSize: number, listView: RadListView) {
    let newItems = this._sourceDataItems.splice(0, chunkSize);
    this.dataItems.push(newItems);

    if (listView) {
        // Call the optimized function for on-demand loading finished.
        // (with 0 because the ObservableArray has already
        // notified about the inserted items)
        listView.notifyAppendItemsOnDemandFinished(0, this._sourceDataItems.length === 0);
    }
}

public onLoadMoreItemsRequested(args: LoadOnDemandListViewEventData) {
    const that = new WeakRef(this);
    const listView: RadListView = args.object;
    if (this._sourceDataItems.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.get().addMoreItemsFromSource(20, listView);
        }, 0);
        args.returnValue = true;
    } else {
        args.returnValue = false;
        listView.notifyAppendItemsOnDemandFinished(0, true);
    }
}
```